# How can I print ID3 tags using mutagen

Tags: python, tags, id3, mutagen

This code prints out the length and bitrate of an mp3 selected via a filechooser. How do I do this for the title, artist, album, release year, comments, genre etc?

```
import sys
import easygui
import mutagen
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
audio = MP3(easygui.fileopenbox('MP3 Dateien','', '*.MP3'))
print(audio.info.length)
print(audio.info.bitrate)
#print(audio.info.id3.TIT2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3

audio = ID3(path) #path: path to file

print(audio['TPE1'].text[0]) #Artist
print(audio["TIT2"].text[0]) #Track 
print(audio["TDRC"].text[0]) #Release
```

You can also use eyeD3 for more info such as Year, Album etc. You can find it all [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/22/parsing-id3-tags-from-mp3s-using-python/)